# Full screen snippets has an incorrect z-index in post revisions

Tags: bug, status-review, design, stack-snippets, revision-history

Example post with a snippet https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71191950/revisions

[image]

- Click "Run code snippet" and then click the "Full page" link
- The top bar, side bar, and post revisions is positioned on top of the code snippet